# Factors with multiple levels per observation

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a dataframe with a factor that contains some observations with multiple values.

```
> x[1]
[[1]]
[1]"good , very good" 
> x[2]
[[1]]
[1]"average"
```

I can transform it to a vector of lists that look like so;

```
>tx[1]
[[1]]
[1] "good" "very good"
>tx[2]
[[1]]
[1] "average"
```

When I transform it back to a factor it errors with a message like

```
replacement has 3 rows, data has 2
```

Is there a way to handle multiple factor levels in a single observation?
I don't really want it to concatenate the level like "good , very good", but rather treat it like an either or for that observation.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: The base factor type only allows one label per observation. None of the methods in base R would know how to treat these values (like `lm` for example). What do you ultimately want to do with these values? A list of vectors is probably the most useful structure you'll be able to work with.

Comment: It would be great to consider the observation as an "or".  It's not ideal but my only other option is to filter out one of the values, which would be a lot of work. Most of the observations would only have one value.  I was hoping for some R magic!  :-)

Comment: MrFlick, can you think of a way to disregard any more than one item?

Comment: You could just select the first item. If you have a list of vectors, `x<-list(c(1,3), c(2), c(4,5)); sapply(x, '[', 1)` should work.

Comment: That worked, thank you!!  My strategy may have a hole in it but at least I can get something into the model and see what happens.